# Blackberry - App deleted from bbstore

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I have an app hosted in BB APP world. I am planning to remove that app.I would like to know how it affects already installed apps in user devices. I meant whether that app will work or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to delete the app.  However you can mark it as 'not for sale' (even if it is free).  This will stop the app being seen by BB World users, but will not effect users currently running your application - they can continue to use it.